# How to access the data inside a node whose memory location has been freed?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to return the data in the node after freeing the node. But I receive segfault when I am trying to do that (my guess is that when I assign the elem value to the variable data, it only copies the reference. After the memory location of the node freed, we lose the member elem inside the node struct. Therefore it is illegal to retrieve the elem via its reference.). Is there any other way of doing it?

```
void* remove_node(struct s_node** node){
if(node != NULL && *node!= NULL && (*node)->elem != NULL){
    void* data = (*node)->elem;
    if((*node)->prev == NULL && (*node)->next == NULL){
        free(*node);
    }else if((*node)->prev == NULL){
        (*node)->next->prev = NULL;
        (*node)->next = NULL;
        free(*node);
    }else if((*node)->next == NULL){
        (*node)->prev->next = NULL;
        (*node)->prev = NULL;
        free(*node);
    }else{
        (*node)->prev->next = (*node)->next;
        (*node)->next->prev = (*node)->prev;
        (*node)->prev = NULL;
        (*node)->next = NULL;
        free(*node);
    }
    return data;
}else{
    return NULL;
}
```

}

And here is the struct

```
struct s_node {
 void* elem;
 struct s_node* next;
 struct s_node* prev;
};
```

Comment: make a copy of it before you free it

Comment: How do you create a node?

Comment: Why do you free it before you are done with it in the first place?

Comment: It's not surprising that you're segfaulting. You're trying to access memory you have no business trying to access (i.e freed memory).

Comment: Contrary to the other commenters so far, I don't see anything inherently wrong with your code.  It does not appear to be the data that you are freeing, but a node that contains a *pointer* to that data.  You in fact *do* make a copy of the needed information (the pointer to the data) before freeing the node.  There is not enough information here to determine what's wrong; you are more likely to get help if you present a [mcve].

Comment: I did not allocate any memory for *elem.....

Comment: Yes I'd say the problem is elsewhere. We need to see how you are declaring and/or allocating memory for struct node's, and struct node pointers, as well as anything elem is pointing to. The function you have posted doesn't seem to have any problem. What you are doing in no way requires a pointer to a pointer, so I'd say somewhere you have confused yourself in the way you are decalring nodes and node pointers.

Comment: @Echo111, whether you allocated memory for `elem` or not is irrelevant.  You don't need to allocate memory to get a valid pointer.  In fact, whether `elem` is a valid pointer doesn't even matter for the code you've presented.  We're not going to be able to help you with only what you've presented so far.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I believe the OP is retrieving the contents of memory pointed by `elem`. So returning an unallocated memory will matter because the caller is attempting to dereference it. This is my understanding of his question.

Comment: You only remove the node if its `elem` member is non `NULL`. Is this intended or is it likely to have side effects?  You might also way to set `*node = NULL` after calling `free(*node);`

Comment: I think the point here is: we are assuming elem is a pointer, because of the assignment to void pointer. We don't actually know what elem is. He needs to post full cost, the structure definition, and the way is he allocating or declaring nodes and node pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The code posted does not seem to be causing the bug you observe. The tree structure might get corrupted somewhere else.

Note however that it can be simplified drastically:

```
void *remove_node(struct s_node **node) {
    if (node != NULL && *node != NULL && (*node)->elem != NULL) {
        void *data = (*node)->elem;
        if ((*node)->prev != NULL) (*node)->prev->next = (*node)->next;
        if ((*node)->next != NULL) (*node)->next->prev = (*node)->prev;
        free(*node);
        *node = NULL;  /* safely, cannot hurt */
        return data;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```